# Relational DB to Single Dynamo DB Table

Tags: amazon-web-services, model, amazon-dynamodb

I've read many documentation from AWS and saw Re-Invent Videos. It talks about that any relational tables can be stored in single Dynamo DB (except few scenarios)
I have got below schema in Relational DB that I want to convert in single Dynamo DB but scratching my head, how it should look like.
My Use cases are:

- Get all Attributes by Product / Item number
- Get a specific attribute
  for a Product / Item number
- Get all Item / Product by an Attribute
  name and attribute Value (For e.g. Get me all the Items where size is
  45)
- Get Attribute information by Attribute name (For e.g. Get me
  details about the Color attribute)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use-cases are a **better fit with a relational database rather than a NoSQL database**.

A NoSQL database is excellent for **storing and retrieving data based on a primary key**. For example, "store record #12", or "retrieve record #12". The item that is stored is in JSON format and can contain a lot of information. DynamoDB can also provide **predictable performance** for such requests, making it ideal for speed-critical applications (eg retrieving user profiles in a popular web application).

However, NoSQL is not ideal if you wish to search for data such as "Get me all the Items where size is 45". You can achieve some of this by adding additional indexes, but it can become complex and is not as flexible as a relational database.

Yes, you can "store" relational tables in a NoSQL database, but you can't access them in the way you desire.

Your examples and your diagram would be better suited for a relational database. I would recommend **Amazon RDS for MySQL or PostgreSQL**.

Comment: Hey John, would you kindly be able to assist on a DynamoDB/AppSync question here please?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60929031/how-do-i-use-a-global-secondary-index-in-dynamodb-to-get-the-id-of-a-user-in-m